# Can the Hadoop distributed cache addFileToClassPath .class files or is it limited to .jar files?

Tags: java, hadoop

I've tried the following:

```
DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(new Path("something.jar"), config);
DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(new Path("something.class"),config);
```

The first one works, the second doesn't. Does addFileToClassPath only work for jars? This seems weird because there's also an addArchiveToClassPath method.